# Oracle SQL, Need to repeat a number sequence based on the count of regexp from another column

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, split

I am having csv data in column named component_id in form of `800230,6015,6312,6315,700255,800170,`
using the count of the comma I need to generated a unique sequence for the component_id in another column named component_instance_id.
e.g. `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`

```
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
|           Component_id              |   Component    |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| 800230,6015,6312,6315,700255,800170 | 1,2,3,4,5,6    |
| 800230,6015,6312,6315,700255,800170 | 7,8,9,10,11,12 |
| 800230,6015,6312,6315               | 13,14,15,16    |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Let the community know what have you tried. Show your efforts and then ask where you are stuck.

Comment: What does the value `800230` appear as Component `1`, `7`, and `13` in the first, second, and third records, respectively, of your sample output?

Comment: Hi Tim component_id is shared by several customers, where as component_instance_id which I am trying to generate as a sequence is unique for each customer and component_id combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use :

> - **REGEXP_COUNT**  : To count the number of occurrences of comma
> - **REGEXP_SUBSTR** : To split the delimited string into rows
> - **CONNECT BY**    : For row generation
> - **LISTAGG**       : For string aggregation

See [**Split comma delimited strings in a table in Oracle**](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/split-comma-delimited-strings-in-a-table-in-oracle/)

For example,

```
SQL> WITH t_1 AS
  2    ( SELECT '800230,6015,6312,6315,700255,800170' component_id FROM dual
  3    UNION ALL
  4    SELECT '800230,6015,6312,6315,700255,800170' FROM dual
  5    UNION ALL
  6    SELECT '800230,6015,6312,6315' FROM dual
  7    ),
  8    t AS
  9    ( SELECT ROWNUM ID, component_id FROM t_1
 10    )
 11  SELECT listagg(text, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
 12  ORDER BY cv) component_id,
 13    listagg(rn, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
 14  ORDER BY cv) component_instance_id
 15  FROM
 16    (SELECT id, lines.column_value cv,
 17      rownum rn,
 18      trim(regexp_substr(component_id, '[^,]+', 1, lines.column_value)) text
 19  FROM t,
 20    TABLE (CAST (MULTISET
 21    (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(component_id, ',')+1
 22    ) AS sys.odciNumberList ) ) lines
 23    ORDER BY id
 24    )
 25  GROUP BY id
 26  /

COMPONENT_ID                        COMPONENT_INSTANCE_ID
----------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------
800230,6015,6312,6315,700255,800170 1,2,3,4,5,6
800230,6015,6312,6315,700255,800170 7,8,9,10,11,12
800230,6015,6312,6315               13,14,15,16

SQL>
```

**NOTE :** The WITH clause is only to build the sample data for demonstration. You need to only use the query and rename the table names per your requirement.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, I am also having other columns in the table which has component_id column can you also advise how can I add them as well in the select statement.

Comment: @VikasSrivastava You have not posted the create and insert statements. You have not shown what have you tried. I have build a test case for you and given a complete working solution. I have used exact column names, how difficult is it for you to extrapolate it to other columns? You should mark it as answered, and try yourself for the remaining columns.

Comment: @VikasSrivastava Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/tour to understand how this site works. If you find a answer helpful, upvote it. If it answers your question, mark it as answered.

Comment: Kumar, Thanks a lot i will try to figure it out on my own.

Comment: @VikasSrivastava come back if you get stuck. Edit your question and show where you are stuck to further help you. All the best!